# Can't stop the navigation bar from breaking in two lines in bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to learn how to work with the bootstrap framework, but i'm having trouble in manipulating bootstrap.css.

I have this navigation bar with collapse feature. I know that it triggers when the viewport is lesser than bootstrap's media queries variables. Ok, I read numerous treads in Stack Overflow and other sites, but still I couldn't fix it.
When i resize the browser to about 880px the navibar breaks in two rows. Searching for solutions for this unwanted behavior, I discovered that there's two ways of  fixing this, one is to custumize bootstrap's media queries variables and compile it again (what I already did) or tweak bootstrap stylesheet.
The problem is that I'm not good in neither bootstrap or CSS layouting...
That's why I came to seek the knowledge of the pros. So what I want to acomplish is:

- Stop the navibar from breaking in two rows;
- Make the navibar displayable (not collapsed) the most I can (given the width space I have to work with for it to be displayable and when the width is too short make it collapse).
- Do it through CSS only (if possible).

Here's the code:

Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Royal Designs</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<header> <!-- Header Section -->

    <!-- Responsive Navigation links and Search box -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Logo and dropdown button in smaller viewports -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
                <a href="/"><div class="nav-brand"></div></a>
            </div> <!-- end of nav-header -->
            <!-- Links in dropdown button in smaller viewports -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Início</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sobre Nós</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
                    <!-- Search bar and Submit button -->
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label for="searchbox">
                                <input id="searchbox" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." name="searchbox">
                            </lable>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                            </div> <!-- input-group -->
                        </div> <!-- input-group -->
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- end of collapse-->
        </div> <!-- end of container-fluid -->
    </nav> <!-- end of navbar -->

</header><!-- End of header Section -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS: I tryed so meny things that I found searching for a solution that I don't know what's taking affect or not anymore. Added the changes suggested by Dr Brad. The stylesheet is as follows:

```
/* ------    Media query: do navbar collapse due to viewport    -----*/
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav li {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 880px;
        overflow: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
/* --------   End Collapsed Navbar Media Query    --------*/
```

**In time:** changing the bootstrap media query from 768px to 900px works (I tested it), though I would like an alternate solution for this through CSS, if possible.

**Thought:** I think it might be less painfull to do this from scratch instead of doing it on top of bootstrap stylesheet (if only I was good in CSS...). Open to controversies.

**Note:** I don't have a live example, sry.

Comment: You need to at least provide some of your CSS. In regards to your "In time" section, `media-queries` are CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the style.css file that you are using for this so it will be a little difficult to determine how to fix your issue. My best bet is that you set style for <li> to have a width: 100%; and if the issue continues add a min-width: 880px; The other option is have overflow: none; and add white-space: nowrap;. Again with the information provided I can't say that this will work but worth a try.

Comment: I tryed to do what you suggested me, but I'm not quite sure if I understood what you told me to do. I added a media query  for a viewport of a maximum of 900px and added the styles for the <li> tags and the min-width; overflow and white-space in the container, but it didn't work, so I tryed to swap the styles to the navbar-nav, but it didn't work either. With the changes added now, the navbar under 880px collapses and shows it's content fully collapsed, it doesn't show the toggle button, it goes straight to collapsed state at once.. How can I edit my question and add the CSS?

Comment: I was saying try the width stuff on LI and if that didn't work do the other 2 styles in li. There's an edit button just under the text on your post.

Comment: I updated my question. The navbar doesn't show the toggle button anymore. Sorry if I'm a complete stupid at this.

Comment: No worries I'll take a look at the code and fix it :)

Comment: Updated the rules in the stylesheet again for the <li> tags. Thank you for your support ;D